# UE-V on Windows Server 2016 not working, but on Windows 10 works fine

Tags: windows-server-2016, user-experience-virtualization

My UE-V on Server 2016 is conifgured via GPO (just like I did for Win 10).

It doesn't do anything - nothing is ever created in the UE-V folders.  On Win 10 (same config) it works fine.

Does built-in UE-V on Server 2016 actually work?  Does it require template registration?  I'm finding mixed messages out there - some indicated that all built-in UE-V requires template registration, but I never did that on Win 10, it worked fine.

Anyone got actual hands-on experience making this work?  Thanks.